# Error when download source code from sf.net through SVN

Tags: svn, sourceforge

Error when download source code from sf.net through SVN:

Error validating server certificate for 'https://svn.code.sf.net:443':
 - The certificate is not issued by a trusted authority. Use the
   fingerprint to validate the certificate manually!
 - The certificate hostname does not match.
Certificate information:
 - Hostname: 216.34.181.157
 - Valid: from Sep 16 08:55:47 2014 GMT until Nov 15 08:55:47 2014 GMT
 - Issuer: 1612140019, Blue Coat SG9000 Series, Some-State,
 - Fingerprint: 2a:7b:6e:a2:49:f9:f6:08:b6:a0:4b:33:b2:85:9d:be:0a:d9:50:8a
(R)eject, accept (t)emporarily or accept (p)ermanently? t
svn: Server sent unexpected return value (503 Service Unavailable) in response to OPTIONS request for 'https://svn.code.sf.net/p/kaldi/code/trunk'
[dpeuser@dpev210 kaldi]$ sudo svn co https://svn.code.sf.net/p/kaldi/code/trunk kaldi-trunk
Error validating server certificate for 'https://svn.code.sf.net:443':
 - The certificate is not issued by a trusted authority. Use the
   fingerprint to validate the certificate manually!
 - The certificate hostname does not match.
Certificate information:
 - Hostname: 216.34.181.157
 - Valid: from Sep 16 08:55:47 2014 GMT until Nov 15 08:55:47 2014 GMT
 - Issuer: 1612140019, Blue Coat SG9000 Series, Some-State,
 - Fingerprint: 2a:7b:6e:a2:49:f9:f6:08:b6:a0:4b:33:b2:85:9d:be:0a:d9:50:8a
(R)eject, accept (t)emporarily or accept (p)ermanently? p
svn: Server sent unexpected return value (503 Service Unavailable) in response to OPTIONS request for 'https://svn.code.sf.net/p/kaldi/code/trunk'

How to do ?

Answer (score 1):

From `svn help co`

```
  --trust-server-cert      : accept SSL server certificates from unknown
                             certificate authorities without prompting (but only
                             with '--non-interactive')
```

As result

```
>svn co --trust-server-cert --non-interactive https://svn.code.sf.net/p/kaldi/code/trunk/
...
 U   trunk
Checked out revision 4543.
```